# Правильное использование aggregate в MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Всем привет. Стоит монга, версии 3.4.

Есть коллекции children и parents.

Каждый документ из parents принадлежит одному из children, то есть

```
name: 'test',
parent: ObjectID('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

В коллекции orders около 5000 документов, и при попытке их получить я получаю ошибку, что нельзя использовать aggregate в коллекции, размером больше 16 мегабайт.

Вопрос, как мне получить все документы, записав к ним имя юзера из коллекции users (только имя, а не весь документ)

Текущий запрос:

```
DB.children.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'parents',
      localField: 'parent',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'parentFull' // полный док, а хочу только имя
    }
  }
]);
```

Текст ошибки

```
{"name":"MongoError","message":"aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)","ok":0,"errmsg":"aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)","code":16389,"codeName":"Location16389"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никто не смог помочь, сам разобрался и надеюсь кому-нибудь поможет.

```
DB.children.aggregate([
  // Если надо сортируем
  {$sort: {_id: -1}},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'parents', // достать из коллекции parents
      localField: 'parent', // где parent из коллекции children
      foreignField: '_id', // равен _id из коллекции parents
      as: 'parentFull' // положить результат в parentFull
    }
  },
  // записать имя из parentFull в parentName
  {
    $addFields: {
      parentName: '$parentFull.name'
    }
  },
  // Удалить parentFull
  {
    $project: {
      parentFull: 0
    }
  }
], (err, ok) => {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

Тем самым у нас к каждому ребёнку записалось имя родителя, вместо того, чтобы писать полную информацию о нём. Оставил очень подробные комменты)) если что не так поправьте.